# Does importXML also work for dynamic pages, which need to fill in a field?

Tags: json, web-scraping, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest, google-sheets-formula

Please, does importXML also work for dynamic pages, which need to fill in a field first to show the information?

For example, on this page https://bid.cbf.com.br/ I always have to fill in the date ("Data") before - dd/mm/yyyy - (for example 15/03/2021) for the information to appear. And press button FILTRAR

In case there will be several names of football players, I want to scrape the URL of the photo, the name, the athlete's situation, publication and the name of the club

Or is it better to use another scraper like Web Scraper or selenium?

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not working for content generated by Javascript like the one you put here.
Filtering or searching with IMPORTXML is possible only if search keyword is included in url.

#### Related:

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/)